# New answers to old related questions

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

[Tosfos Within the Same Mesechta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33705/tosfos-within-the-same-mesechta?rq=1)

[Who is the voice of Tosafoth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/who-is-the-voice-of-tosafoth)

[Tosfos vs Tosfos HaRosh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66214/tosfos-vs-tosfos-harosh?rq=1)

The above 3 questions relate to the history of the printing and editing of the Tosaphos collections. [This page](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=23062), and the document in the 1st post, is the summary around but is not linked in any of them. Is it preferable to add it as an answer or comment, and to just one or all of them?

Comment: If the same point/source is sufficient to answer each of the three questions, then the questions are likely duplicates. If the point/source doesn't really answer the questions but is useful information then comments seem appropriate.